# create id dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I am creating a element  dynamically how would i give this an id?

```
_addQuestionElement : function() {
        var el = new Element('div');
        el.addClass('dg-question-label');
        el.set('html', this._getCurrentQuestion().label);
        $(this.html.el).adopt(el);
    },
```

im using moo tools and jquery.

Many Thanks

Comment: dynamically as in randomly generated, or just wondering how to set a specific id in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give it like this,

```
var uniqueNumber = 1; //define uniqueNumber globally and increament at each element creation
```

With javascript

```
el.id = 'idprefix' + uniqueNumber++)
```

With jQuery

```
$(el).attr('id','idprefix' + uniqueNumber++);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks like Mootools, here's how I'd do it (cleaned up your code a bit)

```
_addQuestionElement: function() {
    var el = new Element('div', {
        'class': 'dg-question-label',
        html: this._getCurrentQuestion().label,
        id: 'yourId'
    });
    $(this.html.el).adopt(el);
}
```

If you're generating the same element multiple times, your id will need to somehow be unique each time.

You could also do without that el variable (unless of course it's used somewhere further in the function that you didn't include)

```
_addQuestionElement: function() {
    $(this.html.el).adopt(new Element('div', {
        'class': 'dg-question-label',
        html: this._getCurrentQuestion().label,
        id: 'yourId'
    }));
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign the id via (if you created the element with new Element()):

```
var yourCustomId = "myId";
el.id = yourCustomId;
```

Or use Mootools attr-setting capabilities:

```
var yourCustomId = "myId";
el.setProperty("id", yourCustomId);
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, to create a div with an ID, you would do something like this:

```
function createDiv(id) {
    $("body").append("<div id=" + id + "></div>");
}

createDiv("myNewDivId");
```

Answer (score 0):

`_addQuestionElement`, I think you need to generate a unique id for each question element.

```
var IDs = 0;
var pfx = "id_";

_addQuestionElement : function() {
   ...
   el.attr("id", pfx + ++IDs);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = $('<div />') .attr('id', myVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

all elements created or accessed by MooTools automatically get a unique `uid` (for the DOM) anyway, saves you from having to keep state yourself (if you want to be doing this automatically).

`console.log( Slick.uidOf( new Element('div') ) )`

so...

```
_addQuestionElement: function() {
    var el = new Element('div.dg-question-label', {
        html:  this._getCurrentQuestion().label
    });

    // prefix number with uid-
    el.set('id', 'uid' + Slick.uidOf(el)).inject(this.html.el);    
},
```

to give it an id via the combined element constructor, it goes:

`var el = new Element('div#someid.dg-question-label')` or add it in the properties passed to the constructor:

`new Element('div', { id: 'foo' })`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery plugin [idfy](https://github.com/pigulla/jQuery.idfy).

*Full Disclosure*: I wrote that plugin :)